# Rails named routes. When should you use them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-routes

A simple question. I'm wondering what the proper way to do this is. Say you have this:

```
Event
Venue.has_many :events
Performer.has_many :events
```

And for routing:

```
resources :venues do
  resources :events
end

resources :performers do
  resources :events
end
```

And you are in events/index.html.haml. What is the proper way to link to an internal action?

---

**Option 1**

```
= link_to "New event", {:action => :new}
```

---

**Option 2**

Using a named route like?

```
= link_to "New event", params[:performer_id] ? new_performer_event_path(params[:performer_id) : new_venue_event_path(params[:venue_id])
```

---

**Option 3**
or do you use a shallow route?

```
= link_to "New event", new_event_path
```

---

Just curious what the proper / industry standard way of doing this is. Isn't option 2 bad practice in general?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need nested `resources :events`?

If so, you could use
`= link_to "New event", [@parent, @event]` in *events/index.html.haml*
and

```rb
def index  
  @parent = Performer.find_by_id(params[:performer_id]) || Venue.find_by_id(params[:venue_id])  
  @event = Event.new  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want your url to be. if you want it to be

```
/performers/:performer_id/events/new
```

then go for

```
new_performer_event_path(params[:performer_id)
```